# Migration of contents from One Liferay portal to another

Tags: migration, liferay, liferay-6, portal

I have some pages, webcontents, communities etc. in a liferay portal whose version is 6.0.5 Now I want to migrate these contents to another liferay portal whose version is 6.1.0 I tried these by using the below method

Create a lar file using Export method in the liferay 6.0.5
Import that lar file in the liferay verson 6.1.0

But its giving the below error:

```
ERROR [ImportLayoutsAction:85] com.liferay.portal.LayoutImportException: LAR build number 6005 does not match portal build number 6100
com.liferay.portal.LayoutImportException: LAR build number 6005 does not match portal build number 6100
    at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.doImportLayouts(LayoutImporter.java:325)
    at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.importLayouts(LayoutImporter.java:140)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceImpl.importLayouts(LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java:1369)
```

Probably its because of the liferay version mismatch. I also changed the manifest.xml in the lar file from  `build-number="6005"` to `build-number="6100"`. But its still not working. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Please note that I am not trying to update the liferay version, I am migrating the contents from one liferay portal (version 6.0.5 to another version 6.1.0)

Comment: The best way to do this is: 1) migrate your actual liferay on a tird server 2) Export/import your LAR

Comment: @Biswajit What about users? how can we migrate it to 6.1 to 6.2?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try 
1) change manifest.xml file from the LAR file as described [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2102638), OR 
2) upgrade your Liferay 6.0.5 to 6.1.0 using Liferay's standard upgrade process as explained [here](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/upgrading-lifer-5).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing the manifest.xml, but its not working.

Also upgrading the version from 6.0.5 to 6.1.0 is not possible in our case as the older version is handled by a third party and masimum we can get the contents from them only in some kind of dump file(e.g .lar)

Is there any other possible way for this migration.